# Adjacency List for Graphs in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having problems printing vertices when using Adjacency Lists. I want to get only the starting vertices, without the neighbours, but I get their addresses instead. So, I'm having an issue with pointers. Right now I don't get why it's not printing the correct output. My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct ADI{
    int val;
    struct ADI *urm;
}ADI;

ADI *adjancencyList( int vertex )
{
  int neigh,i;
  ADI *head, *elem, *vec;
  head = ( ADI* ) malloc( sizeof( ADI ) );
  head->val = vertex;
  elem = head;
  printf( "Input number of neighbours:" );
  scanf( "%d", &neigh );
  for( i = 0; i < neigh ; i++)
    {   printf( "Neighbour:" );
        vec = ( ADI* ) malloc( sizeof( ADI ) );
        elem->urm = vec;
        scanf( "%d", &elem->val );
    }

  return head;
}
int main()
{   int i, n, v;
    printf("Input number of vertices ");
    scanf( "%d", &n );
    ADI *A = ( ADI* ) malloc( n * sizeof( ADI ) );

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Input vertex name:" );
        scanf( " %d ", &v );
        A = adjancencyList( v );
        A++;
    }

    A = &( A[0] );

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
     printf(" %d ", A->val  );
     printf( " \n " );
     A++;
    }
     return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: "Great minds..."

Comment: Note that trailing spaces in `scanf()`-family format strings are diabolical if the input ever comes from a user rather than a file.  The basic problem is that the `scanf()` function won't return until it comes across something that isn't a white space character after the actual input.

Comment: Note: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: In your `adjacencyList()` function, you are not properly initializing each allocated adjacent node, and you are not linking them into a list properly.  In fact, you're leaking all but the last node allocated.  This leads to profoundly 'undefined behaviour' and anything is possible after you use undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is causing memory leak. You should use an array of `ADI*`, not an array of `ADI`, to store what is returned from `adjancencyList()`. Using subscripting looks better than incrementing in this case. One more tips is that `A = &( A[0] );` does virtually nothing.

Also note that they say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Try this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i, n, v;
    printf("Input number of vertices ");
    scanf( "%d", &n );
    ADI **A = malloc( n * sizeof( ADI* ) );

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Input vertex name:" );
        scanf( " %d ", &v );
        A[i] = adjancencyList( v );
    }

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf(" %d ", A[i]->val  );
        printf( " \n " );
    }
     return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! From what I read I expected the use of double pointers was needed. Can you please explain why is that the correct form? Am I not pointing to the first address of my vector? Also, I used     A= &(A[0]) so I was at that first address again, after the end of the      for.

Comment: @AlexPostolache This usage of `A` in `main()` is correct (your `adjancencyList()` is also wrong as pointed out by @JonathanLeffler ) because the type of `A` suits for type of elements (`ADI*`). Your `A` *was* pointinag at what is allocated via `malloc()`, but it is overwritten by the assignment `A = adjancencyList( v );`. `A= &(A[0])` is equivalent to `A= &(*(A+0)`, which is equivalent to `A=&*A`, which is equivalent to `A=A`, which has no effort.